# Android/OpenglES2 : Mapping Java objects into shader structs?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGLES2 programming on Android.I was wondering how to map Java classes to attributes/uniforms in Shader program.
Say in my shader I have defined structure called "light" :

```
    struct light {
        vec4 position; 
        vec4 ambient_color;
        vec4 diffuse_color;
        vec4 specular_color;
        vec3 spot_direction;
        vec3 attenuation_factors;
        float spot_exponent;
        float spot_cutoff_angle;
        bool compute_distance_attenuation;
    };

uniform light light_state[8];
```

And If I write a Java class reflecting same structure as follows :

```
public class Light{
 public float[] position=new float[4];
 public float[] ambient=new float[4];
 public float[] diffuse=new float[4];
 public float[] specular=new float[4];
 public float[] spotDirection=new float[3];
 public float[] attenFactors=new float[3];
 public float spotExponent;
 public float spotCutoffAngle;
 public boolean computeDA;
}
```

Is it possible to map instances of Light into Shader program ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think it's possible, you'll have to upload the values individually. Regular OpenGL has a concept of Uniform Buffer Objects which might be similar to what you want, but I don't see any mention of them in the GLES api.

Comment: Even uniform buffers will break with Java's stupid dynamically allocated arrays, but +1 of course.